# Import Custom Fonts into Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, fonts

I am having trouble figuring how how to import custom fonts into next js 13. The first problem is that the next js documentation has a thorough example of how to do this with google fonts, but they don't list anything about using typekit. The other thing is that almost ALL the examples online I have seen talking about this claim to be using Next JS 13, however they all fail to recognize the different between the new App directory and the old Pages directory. Per next js 13 documentation regarding fonts:

> While inlining CSS still works in pages (next js v. 12), it does not work in app (next js v. 13). You
> should use next/font instead.

So, here is the documentation talking about this new next/font method for version 13:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts

However, this documentation only show how to do google fonts; even the video at the top of the page shows them using the old pages directory.

So, how can I import and use custom TYPEKIT fonts into Next.JS 13 using the new next/font method for the new App directory?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is [Next.js local fonts](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#local-fonts)

Copy your fonts into your project somewhere. You can colocate them with your theme/branding code, but I like to place them in a `public/fonts` folder because it's easier to reference them in my storybook config.

Create some file like `fonts.ts` and export your font config

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";

export const MyCustomFont = localFont({
  // Define a css variable to use down the line --> e.g. font-family: var(--my-custom-font)
  variable: "--my-custom-font",
  // Define variants for your font. 
  // weight = "font-weight". will use the matching variant when you
  // set font-weight CSS prop on your text elements
  src: [
    {
      path: "path/to/public/fonts/MyCustomFont-Book_Web.woff2", 
      weight: "350",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "path/to/public/fonts/fonts/MyCustomFontNarrow-Bold_Web.woff2",
      weight: "500",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "path/to/public/fonts/fonts/MyCustomFont-Bold_Web.woff2",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  // Or, you can define a single font instead e.g.
  // src: "path/to/public/fonts/MyCustomFont-Book_Web.woff2"
});
```

Reference your local font in your theme/CSS.

Example using Material UI:

```
// theme.ts
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { MyCustomFont } from "./path/to/fonts";

export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: MyCustomFont.style.fontFamily
  }
})
```

```
<Typography fontWeight={350}>My Custom Font Book</Typography>
<Typography fontWeight={500}>My Custom Font Narrow</Typography>
<Typography fontWeight={700}>My Custom Font Bold</Typography>
```

Example using Tailwind

```
// app/layout.tsx
import { MyCustomFont } from "./path/to/fonts";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${MyCustomFont.variable}`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

```
// tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [ ... ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--my-custom-font)'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to your adobe creative cloud. Sync font(s) to your cc account.
On windows go to

> `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r\`

OSX: Macintosh

> `HD/Users/YOURNAME/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r/`

There you will find all your typekit fonts file locally, which are synced to your CC.
Rename the file(s) to `.ttf`.

Import that file to your nextjs project folder.
Then use nextjs local font optimisation.

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local'
const myFont =localFont({src:*font_file_path* })
```